# Rails includes doesn't load desired data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two simple models, ProjectSetting and ProjectSettingQuestions. ProjectSettingQuestions belongs to ProjectSetting. I want to load ProjectSettingQuestions data when I query ProjectSetting. Can't seem to possibly do that with this query:

```
 ProjectSetting.includes(:project_setting_questions).where(:project_id=>params[:project_id])
```

params is not the issue. This line gets ProjectSetting data but not the questions. Thanks!

Logs show the following:

```
ProjectSetting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "project_settings".* FROM "project_settings" WHERE    "project_settings"."project_id" = 31 LIMIT 1
ProjectSettingQuestion Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "project_setting_questions".* FROM "project_setting_questions" WHERE "project_setting_questions"."project_setting_id" IN (2)
```

Comment: What do you models look like, just for paranoia, and what is the query is produces in the log?

Comment: I edited the post to include logs. It selects the questions but not the content, which is weird. First time I've tried includes though so I'm not sure.

Comment: Your query log indicates that it's at least looking for the questions. How are you testing to see whether it retrieved any questions?

Comment: Just querying via console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship, you can do it like this:

```
project_setting = ProjectSetting.first
project_setting.project_setting_questions
```

Or you can also do it this way, since `ProjectSettingQuestions` belongs_to `ProjectSetting`, it contains the `foreign_key` of `ProjectSetting`

```
project_setting = ProjectSetting.first
ProjectSettingQuestion.where(:project_setting_id => project_setting.id)
```

You should take a look at this guide if you haven't already:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Hope it helps.